# How can I add f:selectItem with the message "select..." to h:selectOneMenu of objects (JSF)?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, selectonemenu

I am working with `JSF 2.2` and I would like the next `alert` message (picture) don't show when user selected the `"Seleccione..."`message:

[image]

[serverERROR: class javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException Cannot convert Seleccione... of type class java.lang.String to class modelo.entidades.Equipo]

My Bean is:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Bean{

    private String message;
    private Equipo equipoSelected;
    private List<Equipo> equipos;

    public Bean() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        message = "Seleccione...";
        equipos = new ArrayList<Equipo>();
        equipos.add(new Equipo(/*....*/));
        equipos.add(new Equipo(/*....*/));
        equipos.add(new Equipo(/*....*/));
        equipoSelected = new Equipo();
    }

    public void updateSelected(){
        //...
    }

    public setMessage(String message){
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage(){
        return message;
    }

    public void setEquipos(List<Equipo> equipos){
        this.equipos = equipos;
    }

    public List<Equipo> getEquipos(){
        return equipos;
    }
    public void setEquipoSelected(Equipo equipoSelected){
        this.equipoSelected = equipoSelected;
    }

    public Equipo getEquipoSelected(){
        return equipoSelected;
    }



}
```

and the xhtml code is:

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.equipoSelected}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue = "#{null}" itemLabel="#{bean.message}"/>
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.equipos}" var="equipo" itemLabel="#{equipo.name}" itemValue="#{equipo}"/>
        <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.updateSelected}" render="@form" execute="@form"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

thank you!

Comment: What happens if you delete the row `<f:selectItem itemValue = "#{null}" itemLabel="#{bean.message}"/>`?

Comment: I guess the main problem is the missing converter, but you're right, `null` values are always error-prone, so I, too, suggest to replace it with something else.

Answer (score 0):

You're using objects of type Equipo in the Java bean, but the JSF component only copes with strings. You can fix this using a converter. Here's a good explanation of [converters in general](https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-0/). This [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048801/using-pojos-with-selectonemenu-with-generic-converter) has examples specifically for JSF (both with and without PrimeFaces).

You may also want to adopt the converter of OmniFaces. That's adding another library, but after that, the converter "automagically" does everything for you with almost no extra effort on your side.

Answer (score 0):

Try with add attribute **noSelectionOption="true"** in tag **f:selectItem**.

These other question maybe help you:
[Best way to add a "nothing selected" option to a selectOneMenu in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360030/best-way-to-add-a-nothing-selected-option-to-a-selectonemenu-in-jsf)